# How to play movies on Xbox One or Wii U from a USB stick or an SD card?

Tags: wii-u, xbox-one

I want to be able to play movies I have on a USB stick and an SD card on my Xbox One or Wii U because my PS3 died. I'm finding it impossible on both. What am I supposed to do to play my movies?

Streaming from a computer is not an option. I have kids and they want to turn on their stuff.

Comment: I don't believe Xbox One can read from external storage (yet). Even when this eventually gets patched, it still might not be able to read the movie format and/or the file system on the usb stick.

Comment: This might be better split into 2 questions.

Comment: Sounds like you should have picked up a PS4 if this type of functionality was very important to you. The PS4 does support external storage, and they're working on making it have similar media server capabilities like the PS3 did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**Updated**)
A recent update enabled external storage support on the One. You can read all about it on [the official site](http://support.xbox.com/xbox-one/system/manage-storage?icid=furl_xboxone-storage#bb638ec21e2843f4b65191f64acd273c). For your device to be supported it needs:

- Has capacity of 256 GB or more,
- Uses USB 3.0.

As for the Wii U, all external storage media need to be formatted in a specific format only Wii U recognises so far. Hence you cannot register it with the console, put movies onto it, and then play them. It is similar to how the 360 treated external storage.

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox One [June Update](http://news.xbox.com/2014/05/xbox-one-june-features-preview) introduced external storage support. It will reformat the external drive on setting up, but it will work with movies, music, and games afterwards. The Wii U does not have any support currently for external movies. the external setup is merely for game saves